# C++ overload operator '>>'

Tags: c++, operators, overloading, definition

I have been looking through a lot of different examples and explanations, but none has really answered what I am looking for. I have three classes with a method called **connect** for each one:

```
class foo { ... }
void foo::connect(bar br) { ... }

class bar { ... }
bar& bar::connect(baz bz) { ... }

class baz { ... }
baz& baz::connect() { ... }
```

In my main class, I 'connect' them like this:

```
foo.connect(bar);
bar.connect(baz);
baz.connect();
```

or:

```
foo.connect( bar.connect( baz.connect() ) );
```

(I know this is briefly explained, I can explain it better if needed)

So, I was trying to overload the operator '>>' to have something like this in the main function:

```
foo >> bar >> baz;
```

For the first operator it works, so if I simply do the following, it works fine:

```
foo >> bar.connect(baz.connect);
```

But, when I set the other '>>' operator g++ returns this error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator>>’ in ‘operator>>((* & foo), (* & bar)) >> baz.baz::connect()’
```

I think I'm not overloading the operator '>>' properly:

```
bar& operator>> (bar &br, baz &bz)
{
  ...
}
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Note, that it is not recommended to use `>>` for non-stream and non-bitshift operations.

Comment: Right, but I had even more problems with the operator '>', so I just starte to try with this, which looked like it was working. Anyway, maybe it is not a good idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operators aren't anything magical: they are just functions spelled in a funny way. That is, your statement

```
foo >> bar >> baz;
```

actually just calls [or tries to call]

```
operator>> (operator>> (foo, bar), baz);
```

That is, you need the operators

```
bar& operator>> (foo& f, bar& b) {
    f.connect(b);
    return b;
}
bar& operator>> (bar& b0, baz& b1) {
    return b0.connect(b1);
}
```

Note, that the last `connect()` you have won't be doable using `operator>>()` because the operator always takes two arguments.

Comment: You're right about the calls that the operator>> is doing. I haven't thought that way before and now I see it is a bit of a problem for me. Doing it the way you propose should totally work, the problem is that I cannot do it that way. Anyway, I'll give it a try and let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Although you haven't shown it, evidence suggests that your other operator is the problem. That it looks something like this:

```
foo& operator>>(foo&, bar&) { ... }
```

But in order for this to work:

```
foo >> bar >> baz;
```

You probably want `foo >> bar` to return the `bar` (not the `foo`), so that the next call is this function:

```
??? operator>>(bar&, baz&) { ... }
```

And for the sake of consistency, that should probably return `baz&`, though it is not strictly necessary in this case.

The way you have it (because `foo >> bar` returns `foo`), the second `operator>>` is trying to call this (I'm assuming non-existent) function:

```
??? operator>>(foo&, baz&) { ... }
```

Comment: I do not have that first operator, but I found interesting what you said about the `foo >> bar` returning 'bar' instead of 'void', in this case. I'll try to go that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your overloaded operator takes `bar&` as its left-hand operand and `baz&` as its right-hand operand, but your sample code:

```
foo >> bar.connect(baz.connect);
```

Has a `foo&` as the left-hand operand and a `bar&` as the right-hand operand. Do you also define another version of `operator>>`?

Also note that, quoting from your sample code, this:

```
foo.connect(bar);
bar.connect(baz);
baz.connect();
```

Is NOT the same as this:

```
foo.connect( bar.connect( baz.connect() ) );
```

The order of operations is different; in the second example, `baz.connect()` runs first, followed by `bar.connect()` and so on. This is opposite of the first example. This may not matter in your application but it's something to consider.

Comment: I have overloaded the operator>> for each class so they return an object of the same class:

`foo.connect(bar); // returns void`
`bar.connect(baz); // returns bar&`
`baz.connect();    // returns baz&`

This was done intentionally so I could create this 'notation' with the operator>>, so `foo >> bar.connect(baz.connect());` would actually be `foo >> bar_object_returned`; which by the way works fine.

The problem's that when I have `foo >> bar >> baz`, it says that I am actually doing `(foo >> bar) >> baz`, but it is not complaining about `(foo >> bar)` returning void. It just puts it like that.

Comment: By the way, I totally agree with the difference between the two notations and it is something that I did not realize until now. Thanks!